# have no audio with my nokia model RM 984

Tags: audio, nokia-lumia-830

Have no Audio with my Nokia model RM 984. While inserting battery  heard audio for a few seconds.HELP. Also turned phone, hoping if I reset internet connection, maybe this might solve the problem. But alas, it did not work. I am desperate. HELP

Comment: Can you rule out a hardware failure?

Answer (score 0):

Calm-down please. Tell us what happened before we can offer a possible solution.

As @Aulis pointed....

1. Why did you removed the battery in first place?
2. Did you dropped it somewhere? *(just a blind-guess: liquid inside phone)*

In-short: **What were you doing with you Lumia 830, just before this happened?**

---

I would suggest you to try a **Soft Reset** first:

> Go to **Start Screen.** Then Press **Volume Down + Power** button, until phone vibrates. (can take 10-15 seconds). Wait for it to restart.

Hope this helps!  You are welcome for more trouble-shooting.